# Mocking window. matchMedia with Chakra´s useBreakpointValue

Tags: jestjs, react-testing-library, chakra-ui

I have just upgraded to chakra 2.2.1 and I am experiencing some problems with running tests with Jest and React Testing Library

It seems like it's the [useBreakpointValue](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/hooks/use-breakpoint-value) hook that causes this issue:

```
   TypeError: Cannot read property 'details' of undefined

      81 |     base: aspectRatios[aspectRatioKey]?.mobile,
      82 |     lg: aspectRatios[aspectRatioKey]?.desktop,
    > 83 |   });
```

Up until now, I have been successfully been using this mock suggested in the [jest-documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-methods-which-are-not-implemented-in-jsdom), but after upgrading Chakra to 2.2.1 it does not work anymore.

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'matchMedia', {
  writable: true,
  value: jest.fn().mockImplementation(query => ({
    matches: false,
    media: query,
    onchange: null,
    addListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
    removeListener: jest.fn(), // deprecated
    addEventListener: jest.fn(),
    removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
    dispatchEvent: jest.fn(),
  })),
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error with useBreakpointValue from chakra UI. I was able to solve this by wrapping the component to be tested with ChakraProvider.

```
const { container } = render(
    <ChakraProvider>
      <ComponentToBeTested />
    </ChakraProvider>
);
```